# In what languages or environments will a program NOT be in a well-defined (or stable) state after an exception is thrown?

Tags: oop, exception

I'm learning Objective-C from the book "[Programming in Objective-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321967607)" and find myself comparing it to Java. They are obviously very different languages, but the similarities are striking. Near the end of chapter 9 the author issues the following statement;

> It is strongly recommended that if you catch an exception you only do
>   so with the intention of cleaning up and terminating your application.
>   Why? Because Apple **does not guarantee that your application will be in
>   a well-defined state for continuing program execution once an
>   exception is thrown.**

This is very different from Java, where depending on the exception itself, you *can* continue program execution (eg: if you try opening a configuration file, but get an exception of "File not found", you can select some default values and continue without issues). I believe the same is true for C#/.NET. Probably for python too, but I'm no authority.

I'm ***guessing*** that since Objective-C isn't running on some framework/runtime-environment, Apple can't make any guarantees about program state after an exception is thrown. But that still feels weird since, it defeats one of the biggest selling points of OOP (to isolating issues from propagating unchecked) i.e. if your code catches an exception (barring the object that threw the exception), the rest of your program should be fine.

Without knowing how Apple's Objective-C works underneath, I don't think it will be easy to puzzle out. This got me wondering;

From an academic perspective (and simple curiosity) - In what modern OOP languages+environments will an application be in a potentially unstable state after an exception is thrown?

Comment: I am no expert in the field, but from my experience in C++ I would say that this is not a language issue but rather a question of implementation quality. For example in C++ you can get memory leaks with exceptions, but if you write your program properly it is easy to prevent them.

Comment: Way I see things, there are 2 kinds of implementation. What you mention sounds like program implementation - which will naturally differ on a case-by-case basis. The other, and what I feel more generic kind, is if there are any environment-specific implementation notes to be aware of. Like would this matter if you are running the same code, compiled for Windows/OSX. Or even between .NET and Mono. ... etc. (made a minor tweak to the question to reflect this)

Comment: Apple is just honest about it.  Catching and handling an exception requires restoring the state of the program to the *exact* state it had before the code that failed started running.  This is not often done correctly, very hard to reason about and often skipped while testing.  There's nothing that Apple or Oracle can do to guarantee that this is done right, they can only give you the tools to do it right.